# Why transition doesn't work when background is linear gradient in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the background to be colored with linear gradient when hover in css. Since the transition is very fast, I tried to handle it with transition, but unfortunately it does not work when there is a transition linear gradient. Could someone help me on this?

```html
<div class="scroolspy d-none d-lg-block">
 <ul>
   <li>
     <a href="#">asd</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
<style>
.scroolspy {
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 10%;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
}

.scroolspy:hover {
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
transition: 2s linear;
-webkit-transition: 2s linear;
-moz-transition: 2s linear;
-ms-transition: 2s linear;
-o-transition: color 2s ease-out;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
/*CSS Code*/

.scroolspy {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    background: ;
}

.scroolspy:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
.scroolspy:hover:before{
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML CODE -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="scroolspy d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">asd</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually Gradients does not support the transition property but you can do some transition as discussed above

Comment: You are welcome. please upvote this, if it is helpful for you so that it can also be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately transitions don't work on gradients. You could try a workaround - for example:

- Put the gradient on a container behind the div, and set the div itself to `background:#fff;`
- Then when you hover over the div, you can change it to `background:transparent` and it will reveal the gradient behind it. Now a transition will work.